# Glyph errors in tick labels when using shap values to analysis my model

Tags: machine-learning, fonts, xgboost, shap, chinese-locale

I am using shap package in python to recreate some graphs for my model. One of them is the waterfall chart, which is from the [manual](https://www.kaggle.com/code/bextuychiev/model-explainability-with-shap-only-guide-u-need) I followed generated using the following code(the complete code is too long so please check the manual).

`shap.waterfall_plot(shap_explainer_values[4652])`

however, the minus sign of my graph is missing with the warning message "Glyph 8722 (\N{MINUS SIGN}) missing from current font."

[image]
There are a bunch of questions on stackoverflow related to this problem, all could be solved with

```
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
```

However, mine couldn't. Could anyone help with this particular question?

I tried `shutil.rmtree(matplotlib.get_cachedir())` as well.